# How to close the side menu programmatically in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I'm doing a sample on Side menu and its working fine but when i click on device back button i want to close the side menu if its open.

here is my code :

```
getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(UI.command("Home", FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, e -> clickedOnMenuItem("Home")));
getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(UI.command("Change Password", FontImage.MATERIAL_VERIFIED_USER, e -> clickedOnMenuItem("ChangePassword")));
getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(UI.command("Exit", FontImage.MATERIAL_EXIT_TO_APP, e -> UI.get().close()));
```

I've tried below code for closing the menu but its not working

```
SideMenuBar smb = (SideMenuBar) Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getMenuBar();
smb.openMenu(null);
```

i am looking for some advise/help to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`getToolbar().closeSideMenu();` will do the trick.

You can check the Toolbar API at : https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html#closeSideMenu--

If you really want to do it with the SideMenuBar API, you can use `smb.closeMenu()`, but the use of this API is deprecated.

The SideMenuBar API is available [here](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/SideMenuBar.html#closeMenu--).

Comment: thanks for reply and it does the trick but how to know the menu is opened/showing or not.. because i want to navigate to the previous screen if the menu is closed..

Comment: There is currently no public API to indicate that. It should be easy to add but we are in a codefreeze right now so it won't happen soon. You can file an RFE for that.